# Which is best: "with", "by", or "using"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, by-with

When I tried to write research paper about robotics, I felt confused in choosing these 3 words. For example, I want to write that I use mobile robot in exploring room and creating map of that room as following. Which one should I use?

"Do exploration and mapping of the room **by** Mobile Robot."

"Do exploration and mapping of the room **using** Mobile Robot."

"Do exploration and mapping of the room **with** Mobile Robot."

They sound different in my feeling but deeply look into the meaning I think they're the same. Am I wrong?

Comment: I take it this is from some kind of advertisement. A little more context would be helpful. If there's a problem, it seems to be as much with 'Do exploration' as it is with the following word.

Comment: What I try to do is to write research paper about robotics. My research is about exploration and I create some new algorithm to control the robot to do exploration. When I wrote the paper I feel confused which one I should use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*By* doesn't have the right meaning for this situation.  *With* could work, but it sometimes connotes *along with*, as in *with a companion*, which is not the case.  *Using* is the best bet, since that connotes *using a tool*, which is what we want.  Also, *do exploration* is clunky, and sounds wrong.  *Explore* means the same thing, but sounds much more natural:

> Explore using Mobile Robot.